# How to store results from column in for loop variable as array

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have some rows in a table, with one column called "query_server".

The Invoke_ASCmd command has to invoke twice (2 rows) upon different query servers (called Destination_server) as follows:

```
    foreach($row in $Table | where { $_.cube_name -match $CUBE -and $_.active -match $Active })
{
    $Destination_Server = $row.Item("query_server")
    $sync_output += "_$Destination_Server.txt"
    Invoke-ASCmd –InputFile $XML_file -Server $Destination_Server >$sync_output

}
```

I tried doing this but it doesnt work

```
$i=0
foreach($row in $Table | where { $_.cube_name -match $CUBE -and $_.active -match $Active })
{
    @($Destination_Server) = $row.Item("query_server")
    $sync_output += "_$Destination_Server.txt"
    Invoke-ASCmd –InputFile $XML_file -Server $Destination_Server[$i] >$sync_output
    $i++
}
```

throws error:

> - @($Destination_Server) = $row.Item("query_server")
> - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     The assignment expression is not valid. The input to an assignment operator must be an object that is able to accept
>     assignments, such as a variable or a property.
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidLeftHandSide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array has to be initialized outside the foreach loop. Otherwise it is only available within a single instance of the loop.

Try this:

```
$i=0
$Destination_Server = @()
foreach($row in $Table | where { $_.cube_name -match $CUBE -and $_.active -match $Active })
{
    $Destination_Server += $row.Item("query_server")
    $sync_output += "_$Destination_Server.txt"
    Invoke-ASCmd –InputFile $XML_file -Server $Destination_Server[$Destination_Server.length -1] >$sync_output
    $i++
}
```

Comment: btw, i noticed there was misspelling, its length not lenght lol. but even after fixing that, i am getting error "Invoke-ASCmd : A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running.". this means that the destination server is not right. its either invalid or doesnt understand what its trying to get. also, what is the point of keeping incremental i if using this "$Destination_Server.length -1"?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning. I've edited the typo out. You're right, there is no point in keeping the $i. I've just made the minimal changes to your script to make it us the array right. Just print out $Destination_Server[$Destination_Server.length -1] before Invoke-ASCmd to see which value is stored inside.

Comment: so i have done this instead...$Destination_Server[$i] >$sync_output and it ran successfully...but the output i think is just getting the first query_server, because the output file shows one file with query_server1 and another file with query_server1query_server1. a successful run would output one file with query_server1 and another output file with query_server2 as the name

Comment: wait...so i tried printing out what you said and it actually printed out both query servers! cool...so i put it back in the brackets instead of $i, and i see the output file 1 is named query server 1, which is fine. but the second output file is for some reason grabbing the same file (i think) and naming it like this "query_server1_query_server1query_server2". its supposed to be just one file query_server1 and the other file query_server2

Comment: Looks like there is something wrong with $row.Item("query_server")

Comment: i doubt it, because $Destination_Server[$Destination_Server.length -1] is printing out both query server fine